# Disable checkbox when a picklist is selected

Tags: visualforce, javascript, inputcheckboxes

Type is a picklist and reports is a checkbox. When a certain picklist is selected I want the checkbox to be disabled. I tried using an if statement but it does not work and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help? Thanks.

**VisualForce page**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="getItems">    
  <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="overflow:auto;width:500;height:180px">
   <apex:form styleClass="formId">
       <apex:pageblock id="table">

        <script>
        function openWindowPopup(bid,rid){

                var typeVal = document.getElementById(bid).value;

                var Reports = document.getElementById(rid).checked;



                if(typeVal = "type1"){
                    Reports.disabled = true;
                }
                else{
                    Reports.disabled = false;
                    }


            window.open('https://www.local.com?type='+typeVal+'&rprts='+Reports);

        }                           
        </script>


 <apex:pageblocktable id="pageBlockId" value="{!Assetitems}" var="lines" >     
            <apex:column >
                <apex:commandbutton value="Generate" reRender="table" onclick="openWindowPopup('{!$Component.mybid}''{!$Component.myrid}')" />       
            </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Type">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Asset.Type__c}" id="mybid"/>
                </apex:column> 


                <apex:column headerValue="Reports">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!Asset.Reports__c}" id="myrid"/> 
                </apex:column> 

            </apex:pageblocktable>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: I think I have found all the issues - take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript uses the `=` operator as an assignment operator and the `==` operator as an equality test. Change this:

```
if(typeVal = "type1"){
```

To this:

```
if(typeVal == "type1"){
```

And things should work better.

**EDIT** 
Also, add a comma between your argument list in the function call, ie,

```
onclick="openWindowPopup('{!$Component.mybid}','{!$Component.myrid}')"
```

Finally, you need to work out wether you want to send a `true` or `false` to the window you are opening or set the checkbox disabled.

To actually disable the checkbox, you would code `Reports.disabled = true` assuming that you had a reference to the checkbox component.

To send a `true` or `false` to the window, you would need a reportsDisabled variable that reflects the value of the checkbox disabled state. See the code below:

```
    var typeVal = document.getElementById(bid).value;
var Reports = document.getElementById(rid);
var ReportsChecked = Reports.checked;

if(typeVal == "type1"){
    Reports.disabled = true;
}
else{
    Reports.disabled = false;
}   
window.open('https://www.local.com?type='+typeVal+'&rprts='+Reports.disabled);
```

I have verified this works - I replicated your page.

Comment: Hi CapNZ, Thank you for your very detailed answer I feel so silly missing the ==. However when I try your solution reports comes up as "undefined" in the url, which is ok for when the if statement is true but when its not it still comes up as undefined any idea why its doin this ? Thanks.

Comment: It's ok got it, I created a variable inside the if loop equal to reports.disabled and used it in the url. Thanks again for your help.